# Interplay between additive and multiplicative characters of fields

Tags: harmonic-analysis, fields, characters

Let $F$ be a countable field. Given a double Folner sequence $(F_N)_{N\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $F$, an additive character $\chi$ (i.e. $\chi: F \to \mathbb{S}_1$ satisfies $\chi(u+v)=\chi(u)\chi(v)$, for all $u,v\in F$) and a multiplicative character $\xi$ (i.e. $\chi: F^{*} \to \mathbb{S}_1$ satisfies $\chi(u \cdot v)=\chi(u)\chi(v)$, for all $u,v\in F^{*}$) is the limiting behaviour of the averaging ''correlations''
$$\frac{1}{|F_N|} \sum_{u\in F_N} \chi(u) \xi(u)$$
understood?

I mean, have these objects been studied and if so could you provide some relevant literature? I suspect that for the case of non-trivial characters the averages should vanish, but this does not seem obvious. I also know that if one is trivial and the other is not, then the average does vanish.

Note; $(F_N)_{N\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of finite subsets of $F$ so that
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{|F_N\ \triangle \ (u+F_N)|}{|F_N|}=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{|F_N\ \triangle \ (u \cdot F_N)|}{|F_N|}=0,$$
for all $u\in F^{*}$.

Comment: What do you mean by a double Folner sequence? What is the probability measure you are using to define it? Are you meaning a finite field?

Anyhow, Kloosterman sums are well studied objects....

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned the basic device which is the Gauss sums...

Comment: I give the meaning in the note at the bottom. I don't mean finite field, but countably infinite. Also, I don't use a probability measure, $| F_N |$ for example is the cardinality of $F_N$.

Comment: I am still puzzled. Do you mean a global field? 
Anyways, the usual van-der-Corput trick would simplify this average to the case of a sum of differentiated character (either mult. char. differentiated additively, or vice versa)[at least in the case of some "centered" Folner sequences]. If you do the multiplicative version say, you end up with sum of $\chi(a(h-1))$ for sum over $a$ say, that should be easy to handle (as $\chi \circ (h-1)$ is another character).

Comment: I think my question is valid for any countably infinite field, but sure, you can think about global fields.  I will try to work it out as you suggest, thanks.